# how to sort a nested object that contains date and time based on time in elasic

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index named `store` and it's contain a nested object as a list which is `WorkTimes`.

`WorkTimes` list has open time and close time and maybe it has more than one `OpenTime` and `CloseTime`.

What I need to do is sort this index based on open time and close time.
`OpenTime` need to be greater than current time and `CloseTime` need to be less than current time.

here is my implementation so far:

```js
var allfilters = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<Store>, QueryContainer>>();
            if (storeCategoryIds.Any())
            {
                allfilters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.StoreCategoryIds).Terms(storeCategoryIds)));
            }

            if (storeSubCategoryIds.Any())
            {
                allfilters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.StoreSubCategoryIds).Terms(storeSubCategoryIds)));
            }

            var stores = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Store>(s => s.Index(index).From(from).Size(size)
                    .ScriptFields(sf => sf
                    .ScriptField("distance", descriptor => descriptor
                    .Source("doc[\u0027location\u0027].arcDistance(params.lat,params.lon)")
                    .Lang("painless")
                    .Params(p => p.Add("lat", lat).Add("lon", lng))))
                    .Query(query => query
                    .Bool(b=>b.Filter(allfilters)))
                    .Query(query=>query
                    .Bool(b => b
                    .Filter(filter => filter
                    .GeoDistance(geo => geo
                    .Field(f => f.Location)
                    .Distance(10, DistanceUnit.Kilometers).Location(lat, lng)
                    .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc)))
                    .Must(m => m
                    .QueryString(qs => qs
                    .Fields(f => f
                    .Fields(f1 => f1.Title))
                    .Query(searchQuery)))))
                    .Sort(sort => sort
                    .GeoDistance(g => g
                    .Field(f => f.Location)
                    .Order(SortOrder.Ascending)
                    .Points(new GeoLocation(lat, lng))
                    .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc)
                    )).Source(sr => sr.IncludeAll()));

            var storesArray = stores.Documents?.ToArray();
            var arrayCount = 0;
            foreach (var fieldValues in stores.Fields)
            {
                var distance = fieldValues.Value<double>("distance");
                storesArray[arrayCount].Distance = distance;
                arrayCount++;
            }
            return storesArray?.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you better indent your code to make it more readable?

Comment: I believe providing a small reproducible example of what you are trying to achieve would also greatly help.

Comment: Can you please add index mapping and some sample documents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
var allfilters = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<Store>, QueryContainer>>();
            if (storeCategoryIds.Any())
            {
                allfilters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.StoreCategoryIds).Terms(storeCategoryIds)));
            }

            if (storeSubCategoryIds.Any())
            {
                allfilters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.StoreSubCategoryIds).Terms(storeSubCategoryIds)));
            }

            var stores = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Store>(s => s.Index(index).From(from).Size(size)
                    .ScriptFields(sf => sf
                    .ScriptField("distance", descriptor => descriptor
                    .Source("doc[\u0027location\u0027].arcDistance(params.lat,params.lon)")
                    .Lang("painless")
                    .Params(p => p.Add("lat", lat).Add("lon", lng))))
                    .Query(query => query
                    .Bool(b => b.Filter(allfilters)) &&
                     query.Bool(b => b.Filter(filter => filter
                    .GeoDistance(geo => geo
                    .Field(f => f.Location)
                    .Distance(10, DistanceUnit.Kilometers).Location(lat, lng)
                    .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc)))
                    .Must(m => m
                    .QueryString(qs => qs
                    .Fields(f => f
                    .Fields(f1 => f1.Title))
                    .Query(searchQuery)))))
                    .Sort(sort => sort
                    .GeoDistance(g => g
                    .Field(f => f.Location)
                    .Order(SortOrder.Ascending)
                    .Points(new GeoLocation(lat, lng))
                    .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc)
                    )).Source(sr => sr.IncludeAll()));

            var storesArray = stores.Documents?.ToArray();
            var arrayCount = 0;
            foreach (var fieldValues in stores.Fields)
            {
                var distance = fieldValues.Value<double>("distance");
                storesArray[arrayCount].Distance = distance;
                arrayCount++;
            }
            return storesArray?.ToList();
```